# Dealing with non-existent time lags when comparing two data frames

Tags: r

Assume the below two data frames, both index by `day`,  where `df1` has a list of fruit. For each `day` in `df2`, I want to know the fruit in `df2$day - 1`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  day = rep(1:20 ),
  fruit = sample(c("apple","orange","grapes","pineapple","tomato"), 20, replace=T))

df2 <- data.frame(
  day = rep(1:20,2 ))
```

How can I deal with the fact that in day 1 for `df2`, there is no day - 1 in `df1`? I have tried this for loop:

```
out <- c() 

for (day in unique(df2[,"day"])) {
out <- as.data.frame(
rbind(out,
  cbind(
    day,
    fruit = df1[df1[,"day"] == day , "fruit"])))
}
```

Changing `fruit = df1[df1[,"day"] == day - 1 , "fruit"]` obviously throws an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a loop here. There is simply no fruit defined for `df2$day == 1`, so it should be recorded as `NA`. To get this, you can do:

```r
df2$fruit <- df1$fruit[replace(df2$day, df2$day == 1, NA) - 1]
```

So now `df2` looks like this:

```
df2
#>    day     fruit
#> 1    1      <NA>
#> 2    2     apple
#> 3    3     apple
#> 4    4     apple
#> 5    5    grapes
#> 6    6    orange
#> 7    7 pineapple
#> 8    8    grapes
#> 9    9    orange
#> 10  10    grapes
#> 11  11    grapes
#> 12  12    grapes
#> 13  13    orange
#> 14  14    grapes
#> 15  15    tomato
#> 16  16 pineapple
#> 17  17    orange
#> 18  18    orange
#> 19  19    tomato
#> 20  20    orange
#> 21   1      <NA>
#> 22   2     apple
#> 23   3     apple
#> 24   4     apple
#> 25   5    grapes
#> 26   6    orange
#> 27   7 pineapple
#> 28   8    grapes
#> 29   9    orange
#> 30  10    grapes
#> 31  11    grapes
#> 32  12    grapes
#> 33  13    orange
#> 34  14    grapes
#> 35  15    tomato
#> 36  16 pineapple
#> 37  17    orange
#> 38  18    orange
#> 39  19    tomato
#> 40  20    orange
```

Comment: Thanks. I realize this works for this simple use case, but I need the loop b/c the actual use case is more complex.

Comment: @ReginaldMilton maybe you could give a more realistic example? The above method  is the way one would solve the actual problem that you posed. If there are complexities that make it unsuitable it would be better to include them in the question to get a better answer. Thanks